# on enter controller call function angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem is that i need to call a function every single time that a route change to a specific state, lets say i have chatController and i have to fire a() every second but if i exit the controller i have to stop a() and when i'm back to chatController i have to restart a()

My code:

```
$scope.stop = $interval(yourOperation, 1000);

  var dereg = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {   
    $interval.cancel($scope.stop);
    dereg();
  });


  function yourOperation() {
    console.log('$location', $location.$$url)    
    console.log('test');
  }
```

Works fine executing every single and stops when the controller change, but it doesn't work anymore if i go back, i tried with ng-init() function but only fires the first time that the controller start, i need it always when i'm on a specifict controller.

Comment: Best way is to use a 'service' to save state.

Comment: is controller re-initialized at all? show your states configuration and urls to switch between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] If it is state then you can use following event to call function every time when you back to state

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter',function(){       
      $scope.callingFunctionName(); 
});
```

Here you may need to add following attribute in app.js state declaration

```
cache: false
```

2] In case you are using modal then controller will automatically get initialize.

just need to call function like following -

```
$scope.callingFunctionName();
```

Comment: Thanks, really help, i just move the looping code to the $ionicView.Enter function and works!

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter',function(){       
      $scope.stop = $interval(yourOperation, 1000);

      var dereg = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {   
        $interval.cancel($scope.stop);
        dereg();
      });
});

Answer (score 0):

hi this code must be in the controller

```js
// .... controller


$scope.stop = $interval(yourOperation, 1000);
    function yourOperation() {
        console.log('hi')
    }

$scope.$on('$destroy',function () {
        $interval.cancel($scope.stop);
    })
```